# Call API from React

Tags: javascript, json, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get React to get the JSON from the Django Rest Framework API. The link is written like so http://127.0.0.1:8000/band/api/1/?format=json and the structure is as below:

```
{
id: 1,
name: "Muse",
date_added: "2017-04-17",
image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Muse_melbourne28012010.jpg",
bio: "Muse are an English rock band from Teignmouth, Devon, formed in 1994. The band consists of Matt Bellamy (lead vocals, guitar, piano, keyboards), Chris Wolstenholme (bass guitar, backing vocals, keyboards) and Dominic Howard (drums, percussion)."
}
```

My react is written like so:

```
class ItemLister extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
         this.state={items:[]};
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/band/api/1/?format=json`)
        .then(result=>result.json())
        .then(items=>this.setState({items}))
        setTimeout(() => console.log(this.state.items), 2000)
  }
  render() {
    return(
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.length ?
            this.state.items.map(item=><li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
            : <li>Loading...</li>
          }
      </ul>
   )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ItemLister />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

The HTML container div stays at **loading...**, the console shows no errors. I know its something to do with the JSON but cannot figure out what it is, any help appreciated!

EDIT:

After adding the below as suggest by m_callens:

> setTimeout(() => console.log(this.state.items), 2000)

the console returns the object that i am indeed trying to get but it still does not render on the page.

```
Object {id: 1, name: "Muse", date_added: "2017-04-17", image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Muse_melbourne28012010.jpg", bio: "Muse are an English rock band from Teignmouth, Dev…eyboards) and Dominic Howard (drums, percussion)."}
```

Comment: Do you actually get data? Try logging out the items in the second .then

Comment: @WilomGfx I added, console.log(this.items) below the second .then and it says undefined.

Comment: Well then you're not receiving the data from the api, make sure it works on the server side.

Comment: Try using a static .json file, if it works you have a problem with your API

Comment: @NowresRafed i previously used http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and it works. I just don't know what it could be about the Django Rest Framework that is not working

Comment: Compare response headers from both

Comment: You shouldn't be logging `this.items`, try `this.state.items` and a timeout of maybe 2 seconds to give the asynchronous `fetch` time to complete, then see what it logs out. You can remove the timeout afterwards if it works

Comment: also consider doing error handling for your `fetch`. just add a `.catch(console.log)` at the end of the `.then` statements to log any error if it fails

Comment: @m_callens i get: [] length: 0, __proto__: Array(0)

Comment: can you update the code in your post to include logging statements?

Comment: @m_callens done

Comment: You're doing the timeout wrong. do `setTimeout(() => console.log(this.state.items), 2000)`

Comment: @m_callens i got the object! woohoo, but it is not rendering. Its showing correctly on the console :)

Comment: update the post with the full object you're receiving if its different from what you have there already

Comment: @m_callens done!

Comment: @m_callens how can i implement a delay so that it render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after the long process of logging and debugging, I think I've figured out the issue.

Your initial state is creating the `items` property as an `array` and thus you're trying to map each item to an `<li>` to render to your UI, however the value you're getting back from your `fetch` call and reassigning `this.state.items` to isn't an `array` but a simple object. Therefore when you try to `map` the object, it fails, also explaining why your `length` condition is always failing.

Instead of directly reassigning `items` in the second `.then` handling of your fetch, replace it with this version of `setState` to maintain the `array` structure.

```
...
  .then(newItem => this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        items: [...prevState.items, newItem]
      })
    )
  )
```

You may also want to push the `fetch` call back in the lifecycle of the component from the `componentDidMount` hook to the `componentWillMount` hook.

Comment: Thank you it works! what are the three dots for before the prevState

Comment: [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). In short, it takes what the previous value of `state.items` was before the current `setState` call and fills the array with whatever was already there, then adds the new one of the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help, definitely learned a couple of things here.

Comment: happy to help! :)

Comment: I struggled with this a fair bit, and the amount of boilerplate we were creating across apps, so I decided to create an api lib that takes care of a lot of this. Check it out and see if it's useful: https://github.com/DigitalGlobe/jetset